# Change a fixed value for a value coming from a column result in error: overloaded method value - with alternatives

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a ready function used to do some calculations

```
def calculateFund(cColName: String, inst: Int)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val colsToSelect = df.columns.toSeq
  
  val days = 30
  val cSeq = Seq("c_01", "c_02")
  
  df
    .withColumn("amount_ta", lit(1.0) - col(cColName))
    .withColumn("high_pmr", round(pow(lit(1.0) + $"funding_ca" + $"funding_pa", lit(1.0/12)) - lit(1.0), 4))
    .withColumn("rate_mpo", $"high_pmr" + lit(1.0))
    .withColumn("amount_pi", $"amount_ta"/lit(inst))
    .withColumn("c_01", lit(-1.0)*when(lit(1) <= lit(inst), (pow($"rate_mpo", (1.0*days-1)/days) - lit(1.0))*$"amount_pi").otherwise(0.0))
    .withColumn("c_02", lit(-1.0)*when(lit(2) <= lit(inst), (pow($"rate_mpo", (2.0*days-1)/days) - lit(1.0))*$"amount_pi").otherwise(0.0))
    .withColumn(cColName, round(cSeq.map(col).reduce(_ + _), 4))
    .select(colsToSelect.map(col):_*)
}
```

Using the function example

```
df.transform(calculateFund("credit_col", 1))
```

It's working fine, but I need to change a fixed value in `c_01` and `c_02` withColumn condition to use a value coming from a column called `set_days`

**Before:**
`(1.0*days-1)/days)`

**After:**
`(1.0*days - $"set_days")/days)`

So, in this subtraction I'm trying to use the values coming from `set_days` column instead of using de fixed `1` value

I'm getting this error when I tried to put the column directly, like I did in the example above

```
error: overloaded method value - with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Double <and>
  (x: Long)Double <and>
  (x: Int)Double <and>
  (x: Char)Double <and>
  (x: Short)Double <and>
  (x: Byte)Double
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
```

I already tried to put on a val, on the function call, but still doesn't work.
Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole expression used in `pow` should either be a fixed value or a `Column`.

`(1.0*days - $"set_days")/days` expression is a mix of `Column` and fixed value, more specifically you're using operation `-` between a fixed value and a `Column`, this is not supported. That's what the error message says: `-` cannot be applied to `Column` as 2nd operand.

You should wrap the fixed value in a `Column` using `lit`:

```scala
(lit(1.0*days) - $"set_days") / lit(days)
```